# Update first duplicate with entry from last duplicate record

Tags: r, duplicates

I want to update an entry for the first duplicate (with respect to an identifier variable) in a data frame with information from the last duplicate. In the data below, I would like the "begin_date" to be the minimum and the "end_date" to be the maximum for that id, while keeping only unique id values.

Change this:

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),begin_date=c(1970,1976,2000,1969,2010,1950,1986,1990,1960,1968,1972,1983),end_date=c(1976,2000,2012,2010,2013,1986,1990,1999,1968,1972,1983,2001))
```

To this:

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4),begin_date=c(1970,1969,1950,1960),end_date=c(2012,2013,1999,2001))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your data in a data frame, then you can use plyr's `ddply` for this:

```
library(plyr)
data <- ddply(data, .(id), summarize, begin_date=min(begin_date), 
              end_date=max(end_date))

##   id begin_date end_date
##1  1       1970     2012
##2  2       1969     2013
##3  3       1950     1999
##4  4       1960     2001
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! (and I've edited my question so as to create a data.frame, oops).

Answer (score 0):

You say it's a data.frame so that is what I constructed:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4),
                  begin_date=c(1970,1976,2000,1969,2010,1950,1986,1990,1960, 1968,1972,1983),
                  end_date=c(1976,2000,2012,2010,2013,1986,1990,1999,1968, 1972,1983,2001))

with( dat, data.frame(id=unique(id),  
               begin_date =tapply(begin_date, id, head, 1),
               end_date= tapply(end_date, id, tail,1) )
 )

  id begin_date end_date
1  1       1970     2012
2  2       1969     2013
3  3       1950     1999
4  4       1960     2001
```

Could also use min and max.

Comment: Thank you for you answer... I'm going to use ddply and min/max because I find it easier to understand.